# how to pass context to filter in django

Tags: django, templatetags

I want to access context in filter:

NOT working example (showing what I want to get)

```
{% for phone in person.communicator_set.all|phones %}
{{ phone.number }}
{% endfor %}
```

templatetags/filters.py

```
@register.filter(takes_context=True)
def context_filter(context,queryset):
    return queryset.filter(validity_range__contains=context['context_date'])
```

But this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

***Updated code as per comments discussion.***

Update your filter function with the code given below:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(takes_context=True)
def phones(context, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
    context_date = context.get('context_date', None)
    if context_date is not None:
        return queryset.filter(validity_range__contains=context_date)
    return queryset
```

After this in your template file you can call the custom filter as below:

```
  {% load filters %}

{% with context_date=your_date %}
    {% for phone in person.communicator_set.all|phones:**context %}
        {{ phone.number }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: no, i want to pass context with all variables to filter - the context from return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request)) - that's why i use (takes_context=True)

Comment: @TomaszBrzezina Understand. I have updated the code this should work. Thanks

Comment: phones requires 2 arguments, 1 provided . I think that takes_context is useless in register.filter

Comment: also Could not parse the remainder: ':**context' from 'person.communicator_set.all|phones:**context'